# Is it advisable for SEO to use dynamic pages when static pages can be used?

Tags: seo, static-content, dynamic

I am creating a website with around 5 static pages of content and 2-3 dynamic pages for products. The page names for these are `product1.asp`, `product2.asp`, and `product3.asp`. The pages would retrieve the product name from the database (approximately 30 to 40 products).

**There would not be too many changes in the content for the products, but the purpose for dynamic pages are to give the user the rights to change the product details.**

Is it advisable to use dynamic pages when static pages can be used?

In case if dynamic pages are kept, what needs to be done for SEO? (Approximately 40 product names are to be displayed)

Answer (score 2):

Using dynamic pages for e-commerce is usually advisable because it's scalable. It's typically easier to store a new product in a database than to create a whole new page manually with HTML for it.

As for SEO, you want to make sure that the URIs are unique and describe the resource accurately. You want all pages to be unique content, not a lot of boilerplate. If you use parameters that don't change the page content, specify that in Google Webmaster Tools & Bing.

Make sure that your meta titles, and descriptions are generated uniquely so that they're not the same across various pages.

Comment: I'd only add to use canonical URLs as indicated [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to avoid duplicate content should your pages be similar in content as described.